# Finding the minimum sum after balancing 2 arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How would I approach this question?

Given 2 arrays which may or may not contain missing values (marked with 0), find the minimum sum of the array such that the sum of both arrays is equal and there are no missing values. Return -1 if balancing is not possible.

For example,

```
     a1 = [1, 0, 3]
     a2 = [1, 4, 0, 0]
    
    output = 7
    explanation: a1 = [1, 3, 3]; a2 = [1, 4, 1, 1]. 
Now, there are no missing values and the arrays sums are balanced/equal.
```

example 2,

```
a1 = [1,2]
a2 = [4, 0]

output = -1
```

I am quite lost on starting this problem and couldn't figure out what algorithm to use. Unable to figure out all edge cases.

Comment: To start, trying solving these examples with pencil and paper. If you don't get any insights at all, then you must work on easier problems.

Comment: You're looking for the minimum sum, so a good start is to change all of the 0's to 1's. Then adjust as needed. If both arrays initially contain a 0, then it's guaranteed that there's a solution.

Comment: You haven't described how we are allowed/required to fill in the missing values. In fact, you haven't even said *that* they should be filled in -- but that can be inferred from your example.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the values that can be filled in? If negative values can be used, the sum can be balanced in all situations.

Comment: Your examples always use an existing value of the array to fill the gaps. Is this a requirement? Should the **same** value be used for **all** gaps, and should it be one that already exists in the array? Should they always be **integers**? Always strictly **positive**? Can you clarify with more examples?

Comment: My bad on not being more specific. Only positive integers should be used, and they do not have to be existing numbers. Neither do all gaps have to have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 possible situation that matter if there's a viable solution.

1. you have no gaps in both array -> if the sum of the arrays equal so this is the minimum sum, if not there's no solution (obviously)
2. you have a gaps in only 1 array -> change all the gaps to 1 and calculate the sum of the arrays.
   see if the sum of array with the gap is smaller or equal than the other one, if it does you can take the first gap you found and change it to be the difference between (+1) to make the equal.
3. there's a gap in both arrays -> there's **always** solution and the solution similar to situation number 2:
   change in both arrays the gaps to 1 and save an index of one of the gaps in each array, sum each of them and take the bigger sum, this is you minimum sum, so like in situation 2, you need to change one of the gaps in the smaller array to the difference (+1) between the sum of the arrays